# How can someone know that two different domains were owned by the same person?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, hostgator

I bought a web-hosting in Hostgator with a baby plan, and bought another domain from Namecheap and hosted it also in Hostgator current plan, both domains had Domain Protection Policy.

How did somebody know that the two different domains were owned by only one person?

Comment: By Domain Protection Policy, do you mean "Privacy Protection" or do you mean that you used some service like GoDaddy's Domain Ownership Protection (which prevents your domain name from expiring)?

Comment: im mean Domain Privacy, and im just wondering how did somebody that 2 different domain was owned by only one person?

Comment: Are these gTLDs? ccTLDs? Who was it that knew? Are they hosted on exactly the same server? There are far too many variables about who knew what to answer clearly.

Comment: the domain is gTLD, that somebody was a registered users from my domain 1 and he tell something about my post on both domain 1 and domain 2, these two domain was hosted on the same server. thank you @GeoffAtkins for patienly answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find out what websites are running on the same server.  There are many tools that can easily give you this information: [websites on same server lookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=websites+on+same+server+lookup).  All you need to do is enter one domain name into the tools and it will tell you other domain names running on the same server.

Along the same lines, there are other attributes that your websites may share and tools to find the relationship.

- Your sites may both run ads from Google AdSense with the same account: [reverse adsense lookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+adsense+lookup)
- Your sites may both use Google Analytics with the same tracking: [reverse google analytics lookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+google+analytics+lookup)
- You may use similar technology on your sites.  Tools can analyze this and suggest similar sites:  [website technology lookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=website+technology+lookup)

Comment: thanks for this answer @Stephen Ostermiller